# Can AWS Eventbridge rules match object inside an array

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm attempting to match events using an eventbridge rule. However I need to match the event if it's array contains an object with some particular properties and I'm struggling with how to do that.

An example event:

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "396bfea8-6311-c1ab-44cf-d44d93014a89",
    "detail-type": "ExampleEvent",
    "source": "example.com",
    "account": "207772098559",
    "time": "2020-05-31T19:44:55Z",
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "resources": [],
    "detail": {
        "Id": "2fbf7f1b0b0f462ba16b6076812f1b77",
        "Data": {
            "entities": [
                {
                    "entityType": "task",
                    "action": "update",
                    "entityId": "bbf74ec6-8762-48d6-b09f-23a97834fc2f"
                },
                {
                    "entityType": "note",
                    "action": "update",
                    "entityId": "bbf74ec6-8762-48d6-b09f-23a97834fc2f"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I would like the rule to match where the entities collection contains any items with both entityType task and action update. I'd imagined it would look like the below but this gets the error "Unrecognized match type entityType" as it's thinking that the object inside the array means I'm trying to use one of the supported match types.

```
{
    "source": [
        "example.com"
    ],
    "detail-type": [
        "ExampleEvent"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "Data": {
            "entities": [
                {
                    "entityType": [
                        "Task"
                    ],
                    "action": [
                        "update"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eventbridge supports [content-based filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/content-filtering-with-event-patterns.html#filtering-complex-example) with patterns, including support of [arrays](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/arrays-in-eventbridge-event-patterns.html). Have you looked at it?

Comment: Yes I've looked through the docs and had a go. The second code block in the question is my attempt at an event filtering pattern. The problem is the array examples only show simple array matching. i.e.

`"items": [
   "item1",
   "item2"
]`

Will be matched by

`"items": [
   "item1"
]`

but what would match

`"items": [
   { "key" : "item1" },
   { "key" : "item2" }
]`

Comment: @cnash have you solved this issue?

Comment: Not yet. I ended up using a Lambda to parse the events in more detail and do what I wanted. I'd still prefer to avoid doing this but haven't had time to look at more.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I am answering your question and you are not trying to pull a single entity out of the event, instead I think you are asking how to match this event.

This is a matched event for the object array. I removed the array is the matched event and I lowercased the `Task` entityType filter since it is case-sensitive.

```
{
  "source": [
    "example.com"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "ExampleEvent"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "Data": {
      "entities": {
        "entityType": [
          "task"
        ],
        "action": [
          "update"
        ]
      }

    }
  }
}
```

**Example 2:**

Here is another example with that is more nesting and mixture of array and object. As you can it treats arrays and objects the same. This is a Redshift alarm that is producing high disk space.

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "c4c1c1c9-6542-e61b-6ef0-8c4d36933a92",
  "detail-type": "CloudWatch Alarm State Change",
  "source": "aws.cloudwatch",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2019-10-02T17:04:40Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": ["arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-east-1:123456789012:alarm:ServerMemoryTooHigh"],
  "detail": {
    "alarmName": "ServerDiskSpaceTooHigh",
    "configuration": {
      "description": "Goes into alarm when server Disk Space utilization is too high!",
      "metrics": [{
        "id": "30b6c6b2-a864-43a2-4877-c09a1afc3b87",
        "metricStat": {
          "metric": {
            "dimensions": {
              "InstanceId": "i-12345678901234567"
            },
            "name": "PercentageDiskSpaceUsed",
            "namespace": "AWS/Redshift"
          },
          "period": 300,
          "stat": "Average"
        },
        "returnData": true
      }]
    },
    "previousState": {
      "reason": "Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [0.0666851903306472 (01/10/19 13:46:00)] was not greater than the threshold (50.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for ALARM -> OK transition).",
      "reasonData": "{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"queryDate\":\"2019-10-01T13:56:40.985+0000\",\"startDate\":\"2019-10-01T13:46:00.000+0000\",\"statistic\":\"Average\",\"period\":300,\"recentDatapoints\":[0.0666851903306472],\"threshold\":50.0}",
      "timestamp": "2019-10-01T13:56:40.987+0000",
      "value": "OK"
    },
    "state": {
      "reason": "Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [99.50160229693434 (02/10/19 16:59:00)] was greater than the threshold (50.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for OK -> ALARM transition).",
      "reasonData": "{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"queryDate\":\"2019-10-02T17:04:40.985+0000\",\"startDate\":\"2019-10-02T16:59:00.000+0000\",\"statistic\":\"Average\",\"period\":300,\"recentDatapoints\":[99.50160229693434],\"threshold\":50.0}",
      "timestamp": "2019-10-02T17:04:40.989+0000",
      "value": "ALARM"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the matched event:

```
{
  "detail-type": ["CloudWatch Alarm State Change"],
  "source": ["aws.cloudwatch"],
  "detail": {
    "configuration": {
      "metrics": {
        "metricStat": {
          "metric": {
            "name": ["PercentageDiskSpaceUsed"],
            "namespace": ["AWS/Redshift"]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "state": {
      "value": ["ALARM"]
    }
  }
}
```